# In WordPress where the content of text widget are stored?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, wordpress-hook

In Wordpress, when we make a text widget in the sidebar, is the content of the text saved in a variable or in the database?

If it's a variable, which variable is it?

If it's the database, which table is it?

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

What I am trying to achieve is that I will make a plugin that will check if the user has created text widget on their site, if yes, then I would like the plugin to fetch it's content, send it to my server, run it through my spellchecker, bring the updated content back and replace the old content of the text widget.

So, this is why I want to know how I can access the exact content of the text widget, as entered by the site owner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Content of Text Widget are stored in `wp_options` table under
>   `option_name > widget_text`. in serialize form

You can use this MySQL query to get that:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` = 'widget_text'
```

**UPDATED**

If you only want to get the content of the text widget then you have to create a custom function which will return the content, provided you know the title.

Here is the code:

```
function abc_getWidgetContentbyTitle($widget_title)
{
    $contect = '';
    $widgets = get_option('widget_text');
    if (!empty($widgets)):
        foreach ($widgets as $widget)
        {
            if ((!empty($widget['title'])) && $widget['title'] == $widget_title):
                $contect = $widget['text'];
            endif;
        }
    endif;
    return $contect;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

*Usage*

```
echo abc_getWidgetContentbyTitle('some txt widget 1'); //replace it with your title.
```

**The code is tested and fully functional.**

Please Note: *I have assumed that you have value like [this](http://www.unserialize.com/s/5f95f68b-c9f3-1829-3a23-00003a7c3e6b)*

---

**UPDATED** *(after reading your exact requirements)*

You can use [`widget_update_callback`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_update_callback/) hook to get the user entered content and then do your spell check and replace it with the update one.

Here is an example:

```
add_filter('widget_update_callback', function( $instance, $new, $old, $obj )
{
    if ('text' === $obj->id_base && !empty($instance['text']))
    {
        $title = $instance['title'];
        $content = $instance['text'];

        //...
        //Now do your stuff and update $content.
        //...

        $instance['title'] = $title;
        $instance['text'] = $content;
    }

    return $instance;
}, 10, 4);
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**The code is tested and fully functional.**

Reference:

- [get_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/)
- [Hook called before text widget save](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/253481/103815)

Comment: There is a lot more text in that column apart from the content entered in the text widget. Is there a way to get rid of it or another table where the content is saved without anything else in the column?

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.unserialize.com/s/5f95f68b-c9f3-1829-3a23-00003a7c3e6b), it stores data as an associative array so you can find the content in `text` key. Do you have only single text widget or multi-text widget?

Comment: I have multiple text widget. The array that you showed.. Is it WP that makes this array? If yes, how can i access it?

Comment: I am afraid I would not know the title(s) of the text widgets as they will be user input. They may even be without titles sometimes. Any solution for that?

Comment: What you exactly want to do can you please explain in your question, that will be helpful to identifying best possible solution.

Comment: I have updated my question with further details, would you like to check?

Comment: Thank you so much. You made my day.